# Linking tables in SQL

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, linq

I'm trying to wrap my head around databases, and as a way of learning, I'm making a poker tracker program using C# and WPF.

Some of the tutorials I have seen on LINQ to SQL use "LINQ to SQL classes" that show the databases and their relations in a neat way, but I'm not really sure how to use it and exactly what code is generated from it.

Say I want to log hand histories in one table, containing data like hand ID, player 1, player 2 etc,  community cards and pot size. In another table I want info on all the players I have met. So every hand history logged is connected to at least 1 logged player, and up to 8 connections.

How do you make these neat visual connections between the tables that I have seen in the tutorials, and what would be the best approach in this example?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better to use Linq to Entity Framework because its performance is better than Linq to SQL.

code example for EF http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246861/LINQ-to-Entities-Basic-Concepts-and-Features

Comment: @MagnusDale: did you try above link?

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I started going trough the tutorial on WCF, and I'll work my way to LINQ to Entity. Thanks a bunch!